# group data on weekly and yearly basis after categorising in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, frequency

Problem statement : data consists of two columns in csv - date and product Data :

```
  Date                  Prod
  1/2/2018  7:43:00 PM     A
  1/1/2018  11:41:00 AM    B
  1/1/2018  7:57:00 AM     C
  1/2/2018  1:56:00 PM     A
  1/5/2018  3:29:00 AM     A
  1/3/2018  7:23:00 AM     C
  1/3/2018  1:26:00 PM     B
  1/5/2018  2:08:00 AM     A
  1/5/2018  3:47:00 PM     B
```

I need to return two json data with product as the key and value should be frequency of product

1. on weekly basis
2. on yearly basis

Like:

1. `[{"A":{"Week1":"3","Week2":"3","Week3":"5",...},{"B":{"Week1":"5","Week2":"7","Week3":"4",...},{"C":{...}}]`
2. `[{"A":{"2018":"3","2019":"3","2020":"5",...},{"B":{"2018":"5","2019":"7","2020":"4",...},{"C":{...}}]`

I have tried :

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

weekly_series = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='W'))['Date'].count()

weekly_series.index = weekly_series.index.week
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepare your dataframe:

```py
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df["Year"] = df["Date"].dt.isocalendar().year
df["Week"] = df["Date"].dt.isocalendar().week
```

Create your dictionaries:

```py
dyear = df.groupby("Prod")[["Year"]] \
          .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts("Year").to_dict()).to_dict()

dweek = df.groupby("Prod")[["Week"]] \
          .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts("Week").add_prefix("Week").to_dict()).to_dict()
```

```
>>> dyear
{'A': {2018: 4}, 'B': {2018: 3}, 'C': {2018: 2}}

>>> dweek:
{'A': {'Week1': 4}, 'B': {'Week1': 3}, 'C': {'Week1': 2}}
```

Comment: This is giving multiple errors, few of them are:
AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'isocalendar'
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

Comment: What is your version of Pandas? `pd.__version__`. Mine is 1.1.15

Comment: From the doc: "New in version 1.1.0. You may obtain the year, week and day components of the ISO year from the ISO 8601 standard"